# Algorithm to create a diagonal pattern through a n x n grid

Tags: java, algorithm, math, language-agnostic, grid

I would like to know the name of an Algorithm that solved the problem listed in the title, or explaination on how to do it, I'll try to explain it carefully, consider this:

```
9 8 6
7 5 3
4 2 1
```

It denotes a 3 x 3 grid, and I want to traverse the grid in the order noted there. The right bottom is the origin (0, 0) and left top is (2, 2).

So in coordinates the traversal looks like:

1. (0, 0) [Level 1]
2. (1, 0) [Level 2]
3. (0, 1) [Level 2]
4. (2, 0) [Level 3]
5. (1, 1) [Level 3]
6. (0, 2) [Level 3]
7. (2, 1) [Level 4]
8. (1, 2) [Level 4]
9. (2 ,2) [Level 5]

With the level denoting some sort of iteration.

Also if it is possible to generate this in a nice way, using java or even java 8, then I'd be happy to see it, because it is I think better as a naïve looping approach.

I'm wanting to use this for generating terrain for a graphics application, as with the conventional iterative approach (loop over width, loop over depth) it creates 'strange' random patterns, at least not the ones I want.

I think I have an idea in pseudo code, given input `n`:

```
while x < 2 && y < 2
do
    "iterate over elements to the top right if they exist"
    if (x < 2) x++
    else
        if (y < 2) y++
```

This would result in the expected iteration.

Comment: An algorithm of this level of simplicity won't have a name attached to it.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could solve this would be to think of each number as an individual node with a left and top neighbor.

So your first level would be the following:

```
 3
21
```

When requesting the node you would pass it the coordinate of 1(0,0) and then return (x+1,y) and (x, y+1) to give the two neighbors.

You can then do that again with any other node to walk the different paths.

The next level would consist of two nodes and their neighbors, for example:

```
 6
53
```

and

```
 5
42
```

So for level two when you pass in nodes 2 and 3 you would get 4, 5, 5, 6 as the results and you could just filter out the duplicates before going to the next level.

The key here is to loop through the list of nodes:

```
for(Node n: nodes)
{
    Node left = new Node(n.x+1, n.y);
    Node top = new Node(n.x, n.y+1);
    //store these nodes in result list
}
```

With a node class that contains an x and y coordinate(you will have to make that object yourself). There is also probably a way more elegant approach to this but I am just trying to get you to think through the problem you are solving.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want, for every "level of recursion" each `A[i][j]` with `i + j = n` n being the level of recursion and A being an array containing your grid?
Something like

```
int[][] A = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
for(int n=0;n < A.length + A[0].length;n++) {
  for (int i=0;i<=n;i++) {
    int j = n - i;
    if(i<A.length && j<A[0].length)
      System.out.print(A[i][j]+" ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

With A being

```
9 6 3
8 5 2
7 4 1
```

You get

```
1
2 4
3 5 7
6 8
9
```

Each line is a level of iteration

Comment: Close, but think about how many items that will print. You can omit the `j` loop and calculate `j = n - i` from your formula instead. Also, as you noted, you need to check that `j` lies within the grid.

Comment: Better, but it will still print twice as many items as it should. By using min you wil address items with negative indixes for `j`. Instead of `min` you should check that `0 <= j && j < A[0].length)` before doing anything with `A[i][j]`.

Comment: I like how you distinguish between the two dimensions in your code, but if you allow for rectangular matrices, your first loop should run up to `A.length + A[0].length` instead of `2*A.length`.

Comment: I don't understand, ``j=n-i`` and ``i`` go from ``0`` to ``n``, how ``j`` can be negative ? And it is not only a question of duplicate, my code take the old value when `n>A.length` (which shouldn't happend, I edit it). And thanks for the ``n`` limit.

Comment: Well, try out your code. Let's say the outer loop is in its first iteration and  `n` is 0. Then you iterate `i` from 0 to `length`. Question: What is the value of `j` when `i` is 1 and `n` is 0?

Comment: Well, I have `for (int i=0;i<n;i++)` so I don't see how ``i`` can be greater than ``n`` ? (`i` iterate from 0 to ``n``)

Comment: Ah! You need to iterate up to the array `length`, otherwise you miss elements. Don't you test your code before you post it here?

Comment: Yes, looks good now. But instead of a post-edit cycle I'd rather you made that a test-edit cycle and post only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can do is as two set of doubly nested loops, first do the bottom left triangle and the diagonal. Then the top right triangle. You can see this running as a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SalixAlba/76zdLbp7/.

```
var size=5;
var x=0;
var y=0;

// Set up data array, store the index of the point
var data = new Array(size);
for(var i=0;i<size;++i) {
    data[i]=new Array(size);
}

var pos=1;
// Bottom right triangle
for(var i=0;i<size;++i) { // should be size
    for(var j=0;j<=i;++j) {
        x = size - i + j - 1;
        y = size - j - 1;
        data[y][x] = pos;
        console.log(i,j,x,y);        
        ++pos;
    }
}

// Top left triangle
for(var i=0;i<size-1;++i) {
    for(var j=0;j<size-1-i;++j) {
        x = j;
        y = size - i - j - 2;
        data[y][x] = pos;
        console.log(i,j,x,y);        
        ++pos;
    }
}

var res="";
for(var i=0;i<size;++i) {
    res = res + data[i].toString() + "\n";
}
$("textarea#output").val(res);
```